# Google App Engine Launcher (Python)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I am trying to run the Google App Engine Launcher. it pops up an error message saying that it cannot find the Python binary file. But I have downloaded and installed Python 2.7.8.  The error message suggests me to modify the Python path in Edit-> Preference. But the Launcher is not responding, it just hangs on there for ever.  What should I do?

Comment: Reinstall python. It should offer you to add it to your PATH

Comment: Thank you very much. I followed your advice, now the error message is gone.  But the Launcher is still not responding. It just stays like that for ever. any further suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google App Engine Launcher Python Path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35621677/google-app-engine-launcher-python-path)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add python to the **PATH Variable**.

Refer to [How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)

**Install Latest App Engine**

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/?hl=en_US dowloand Google Cloud SDK install it then launch Google App Engine launcher --> Edit-->Preferences-->Python path--> new python should be installed probably under the drive C: then select Python27x86 -->pythonw.exe.