# Google App Engine Launcher Python Path

Tags: python, google-app-engine, launcher, google-app-engine-python, google-app-engine-launch

When I install the Google App Engine SDK and run the launcher, it asks me to configure the python location:

[image]

And when I open `Preferences`, it asks for a path to a python executable:

[image]

Which path should I insert and what is the difference:

- C:\Python27\python.exe
- C:\Python27\pythonw.exe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like Google App Engine couldn't find your python installation. It looks for Python by checking the `PATH` environment variable, so it's best to use it.

The short answer is use `C:\Python27\pythonw.exe`. I've just installed the latest "GoogleAppEngine-1.9.33.msi", and after I ran "Google App Engine launcher" (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\launcher\GoogleAppEngineLauncher.exe`), in "Edit -> Preferences" I saw "`C:\Python35\pythonw.exe`". (It is because I have Python 3.5 folder before Python 2.7 folder in my `Path` environment variable setting.) But the point is App Engine launcher (or installer) chose the `pythonw.exe` over `python.exe` all by itself.

[image]

But as a better solution, I would suggest you to set your `Path` environment variable, this will prevent other similar issues in the future.

To set Python on the `Path`, if it's not set:

1. Right click "Computer" (or "My Computer") and choose "System Properties";
2. Switch to "Advanced" tab;
3. Press "Environment variables" button;
4. Double click "Path" variable in the lower list of system variables;
5. In the opened window in "Values" add `C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;` to the beginning of the line. Make sure you don't accidently delete anything there!
6. Press "OK" in this window and "OK" in "Environment variables" window and you're good to go.

Alternatively in item 5, you might want to use user's `PATH` from the upper list. I would set Python for all users as I described.

Now launch Google App Engine via "Google App Engine Launcher" and see if in "Edit -> Preferences" you have either "Default if not set: C:\Python27\pythonw.exe" or "Default if not set: C:\Python27\python.exe" written below the field for "Python path". If there's still nothing similar, then it's not the launcher that checks for `PATH`, but it's the Installer. Then now it's time to uninstall "Google App Engine" and install it again. After this everything should work as expected. (Btw, Installer checks for Python and other dependecies, so it should report if there're any errors.)

The main difference between `python.exe` and `pythonw.exe` is:

- `python.exe` opens console widow when a module is executed with it,
  or, if run directly from command line, executes a module in a current
  console window preventing any further commands until the module
  exits. So basically intended for console applications or debugging.
- `pythonw.exe` on the other hand is intended for GUI apps or no-GUI
  apps, so if a module is executed with `pythonw.exe`, then there's no
  console window is open, if run via current console a module is
  executed in a separate process and the console is available for further
  commands right away. The drawback is no output is provided in this
  case, i.e. no errors printed as there's no console window associated
  with running Python module.

Fore details see: [official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#executing-scripts), [chapter from a book(small but informative)](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/python/excerpts/chpt20/index.html?page=2), [Python mailing list](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2001-September/082292.html).

Now regarding Google App Engine, on [installation page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python) they state:

> You will need Python 2.7 to use the App Engine SDK, because the
>   Development Server is a Python application. Download Python 2.7.X
>   (don't use a higher version) from the Python web site.

So since a server is a no-GUI application, that's probably why App Engine chooses `pythonw.exe`.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer! However, my question still remains unanswered: what is the difference between them? When I use them, I see no difference _in action_. By the way, see this reliable reference by Edward Mitchell: [App Inventor 2 Databases and Files](https://books.google.com/books?id=ryB4CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT85&lpg=PT85&dq=Google+App+Engine+Launcher+Python+Path&source=bl&ots=5hH-h3eohq&sig=Hhzg8riA5pgJxZbXOl6CnYWq1xU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5mPGGuaHLAhWnd5oKHeSKAaU4ChDoAQg1MAU#v=onepage&q=Google%20App%20Engine%20Launcher%20Python%20Path&f=false).

Comment: @Morri, sorry, I haven't found that in your original question, but anyway I updated the answer. Hope that now it solves your issue completely. You shouldn't see any difference, because even with `python.exe` the console window could still be suppresed. P.S. I couldn't see the page on the link you provided.

Comment: Thanks again and sorry for the broken link! Please try [this one](https://books.google.com/books?id=ryB4CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT85&lpg=PT85&dq=%22Step+5+%E2%80%93+Run+Google+App+Engine+Launcher%22&source=bl&ots=5hH-hccper&sig=khUDafOcIXMKe33gkqg7ctPp5PU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwrKuSgaTLAhUoIJoKHWO7CcIQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22Step%205%20%E2%80%93%20Run%20Google%20App%20Engine%20Launcher%22&f=false) and let me know what you think.

Comment: I think, that either they have no idea, that  `pythonw.exe` exists (as e.g. it's strange that they suggest to remove all python and intall again just to fix the `path` variable instead of fixing it directly) or their software will print debug messages to console and in order to do that they need to use `python.exe` over `pythonw.exe`.

Answer (score 2):

According to this QA, pythonw seems to be preferable:
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11246

Here's the similiar question and answer:
[pythonw.exe or python.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705982/pythonw-exe-or-python-exe)

> python.exe is a console (terminal) application for launching CLI-type scripts.
>
> pythonw.exe is a GUI app for launching GUI/no-UI-at-all scripts.

Comment: "_According to this QA, pythonw seems to be preferable_" But this one is the opposite: [Prerequisites for App Engine development are missing!](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3937). "_python.exe is a console (terminal) application for launching CLI-type scripts._" But even if I use `pythonw.exe`, I don't see a terminal window to pop up.

Comment: `pythonw.exe` doesn't pop up a window, but `python.exe` does, according to the explanation.

Comment: Sorry for the typo! I meant: even if I use `python.exe`, I don't see a terminal window to pop up.

Answer (score 2):

From looking at the the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#executing-scripts

Pythonw basically suppresses the console window. I wouldn't think you'd need one using the app-engine, so, pythonw.exe would be my best guess.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says `python=None`. Check if you can execute from cmd `python -V` to confirm your python build is accessible throughout the system. GAE generally can find your python installation automatically, and confirms your python path before installation.

Try [this tutorial](http://www.billthelizard.blogspot.com/2013/12/creating-twitter-bot-on-google-app.html) if its any help.

Answer (score 0):

Pythonw.exe is the executable that does not open the console. Python.exe will open the console. You probably want to use pythonw.exe in this instance because I don't know why you would want a terminal open for the app engine.

https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html

The App Engine SDK also didn't find your installation of python. This is probably because you don't have the global env. variable declared.